# Ajax for changing content without refreshing

Tags: ajax

How do i use ajax to make this function run without refreshing the page?

```
function showModal(id)
{
$(".modal").modal('hide');
$("#" + id).modal();
}
```

id is the id of a modal in bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to open modal using ajax. I will suggest you to use eModal
https://saribe.github.io/eModal/ 
Find what it can do .

Comment: It's better to provide simple example instead of just giving a link

Comment: i don't have to get data from server side i just have to change the content of a modal in such a way that it doesn't refreshes